# Why have Multiple Controllers per View?

Tags: angularjs

We have a new guy at our office that says that I need to break each of my controllers up into several controllers.  Currently, each of my Controllers serve one View (page) each in my application.  I was taught that unless necessary (i.e. two ui-datepickers on one page), that you should have only one controller per View.  For example, I have a View that serves up most of the information associated with a Company.  It brings back all of this information in one `$http` call to the Web Api via an Angular Service.  The information returned is organized and separated into visual groups on the View using `ui-tabs`.  He told me that each "tab" should have its own Controller.  This would mean having about seven (7) controllers on one View.  When I asked him "why" he couldn't really give me an explanation as to why this would be better.  I'm not saying that he is "wrong" but this seems like a lot of unnecessary bloat and work to me as I would have to inherit on each tab to share scope across all Controllers.  If this sounds reasonable to any of you Angular gurus, could you please explain it to me?  I'm a pragmatist, so if it makes sense, I'll get on board.  If it sounds crazy, I'd like that feedback as well.  Thanks for taking the time to read and/or answer this post.  Happy coding!

Comment: I dont see any value added feature on his approach unless each of your tabs are complicated and contains more information. More over, each tab triggers it's own $http request. Not necessary.

Comment: Thanks!   Neither do I, but I don't claim to be an expert so I needed some real feedback from the Angular community.